# How diverse are the sperm cells of an individual male due to random mutations?

Tags: dna, reproduction, dna-sequencing, mutations, sexual-reproduction

Due to the sheer number of sperm cells in an individual and the rate of mutations, are they likely to be incredibly diverse and encompass most of what we see across our species?  For instance would it be likely to find sperm cells that could result in extreme height, intelligence, different skin colour,etc even if the father didn't have any of those genes in their DNA, but a sperm cell did due to mutations?

Comment: A pre-print study was recently published regarding sperm cell mutations. Contrary, to what you might expect the ratio of paternal to maternal mutations was quite stable from puberty and onward. See [Gao, ..., Przeworski: Overlooked roles of DNA damage and maternal age in generating human germline mutations](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/05/22/327098). They conclude that [spermatogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermatogenesis) does not underlie the male bias in human mutation.